# shopify ajax api- getting cart item price

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm populating my cart using ajax but I've got one issue.
I'm basically looping through the items in the cart and then display the title,image, price etc.
So I'm getting the price like this:

```
cartItem.price
```

However my issue is this displays the price as 2700 instead of 27.00. Anybody know how to get this to display in the right format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trix something like this :

```
var price = parseInt(cartItem.price / 100) + "." + (cartItem.price % 100)
```

You will have 27.0 for 2700 and 27.50 for 2750.

Or little more complexe :

```
var cents = "";

if (cartItem.price % 100 < 10) {
 cents = "0";   
}
var price = parseInt(cartItem.price/100) + "." + cents + cartItem.price % 100;
```

Price will be 27.00 for 2700 and 27.50 for 2750.